# Excel VBA: PivotTable CubeField Fact Table Name?

Tags: vba, excel, cube, olap-cube

I'm working with a large OLAP Cube, and I'm building very rudimentary search functionality to help me parse through the amount of data (~30 fact tables, 30 dimensions, plus calculated measures), but I've come across an interesting issue.  When I access a `CubeField.Name` property for a fact table member or a calculated measure, it comes through as `[Measures].[FieldName]` instead of pointing me to the correct Fact table / calculated measure folder.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
Sub X()

    Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
    Dim oCubeField As CubeField

    Set pvtTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    For Each oCubeField In pvtTable.CubeFields
        If InStr(LCase(oCubeField.Name), "spread") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print oCubeField.Parent & ": " & oCubeField.Name
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Any ideas on how I can actually reach the fact table name?  Or the calculated measure's folder structure?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `oCubeField.Value` perhaps. The [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff196040%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for the CubeField object says:

> **Name**   Returns a String value that represents the name of the object.
>
> **Value**      Returns a String value that represents the name of the specified field.

Comment: Yeah, tried that as well - no luck.  In this cube it produces identical results.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do that, because a measure expression may link to a few fact tables.

But you can query and analyse cube metadata with OpenSchema() function.

Something like this:

```
Sub GetMeasuresList()
    Const adSchemaMeasures = 36

    Set ADOCon = ActiveCell.PivotTable.PivotCache.ADOConnection

    Set RecSet = ADOCon.OpenSchema(adSchemaMeasures)

    While Not RecSet.EOF
        Debug.Print RecSet!MEASURE_NAME & ": " & RecSet!EXPRESSION
        RecSet.MoveNext
    Wend

End Sub
```

[OLE DB for OLAP Schema Rowsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/schema-rowsets/ole-db-olap/ole-db-for-olap-schema-rowsets)

[How To Use the ADO OpenSchema Method in Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/186246/how-to-use-the-ado-openschema-method-in-visual-basic)